# How can i Masquerade the 10.0.0.116 IP as 192.168.1.* on my local network

Tags: networking, vpn

What im trying to do here are to connect to an PS3 Mediaserver, thats located remotely behind an VPN.

[this is how my network looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rV0W.png)

PS3 Mediaserver:  IP: 10.0.0.116

Playstation 3:    IP 192.168.1.116

I'm connecting to the remote network, using an Drytek vigor 2920N. Site to site (LAN to LAN). This is how my Lab looks like

The issue here, arent that i cant connect to the PS3 Media server. the issue are that the PlayStation 3, does not se the PS3 media server on the "VPN network" since its on an other IP range. It looks like the play station is only looking for Media servers on its own network range.

I can ping 10.0.0.116, connect to it using ssh from an other computer on the 192.168.1.0/24 network.

So my Questions are:

How can i Masquerade the 10.0.0.116 IP as 192.168.1.* on my local network. Or if anyone know how i can get the PS3 to look for media servers on other network ranges, that would be an equally good solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done, if you have a *Nix pc on the 192.168.1.0/24 network. It can be done on both Unix and Linux, but I will give you the details only for a Linux pc.

The basic strategy is to build a virtual interface on the Linux pc (which will act as an intermediary), from which we will re-route all traffic to the PS3 Server. We use a virtual interface, so that all ports on the regular NIC are left free.

First, you must allow IPv4 forwarding, and inhibit reverse-path filtering:

```
  echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
  echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/default/rp_filter 
  echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter
```

You can obtain the same result by uncommenting and setting to the desired values the corresponding items in the file /etc/sysctl.conf, and then running:

```
  sysctl -p
```

Mind you, this effect is permanent, while the *echo*'s effect disappears after a reboot.

Now we create the virtual interface

```
  ip link add link eth0 mac0 address 56:61:4f:7c:77:db type macvlan
  ip link set mac0 up
  dhclient mac0
```

Then we store the IP address of the newly created virtual interface *mac0* in shell variable:

```
 IPMAC0=$(ifconfig | grep -A 1 mac0 | grep inet | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F ":" '{print $2}')
```

Now we setup policy routing:

```
 ip route add default via Your_Gateway_Address dev mac0 table 200
 ip route add Your_LAN_net dev mac0 src $IPMAC0 table 200
 ip route del Your_LAN_net dev mac0 table main
 ip rule add from $IPMAC0 table 200
```

Now we use iptables to redirect all traffic to the PS3

```
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -d $IPMAC0  -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.116
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -d 10.0.0.116 -j MASQUERADE
```

Lastly, you cannot expect too much speed: the packets are re-routed, compressed, encrypted, and viceversa (de-crypted, decompressed), so that some time will be consumed in these passages.

Comment: I found an alternative way to work this out, and it working well. I'm currently streaming .mvk files over the internet using (NFS server -> VPN -> local PS3 Media server -> PS3) Works well. But this forces me to have an local PS3 Media server installed on my local network. (So i'm going to se if your solution is working whit streaming)